# Dimension Error Razor Syntax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have been trying to create a lookup that queries the database and reproduces it so that you can manage all of the users for the site.

For some reason the For Each is giving an error of expression expected for the Dim.

Any help in understanding the error would be much appreciated.

```
@Code
PageData("Title") = "Admin"
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.vbhtml"

Dim db As Database = Database.Open("StarterSite")
Dim selectQueryString = ("SELECT * From UserProfile BY email")





End Code

<section>
Hello and welcome to the control section of the website:

Below is the table of all of the users... Hopefully

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>email confirmation</th>
    </tr>



    @For Each(Dim row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){ 

    <tr>
        <td> @row.email </td>
        <td> @row.password </td>
        <td> @row.requireEmailConfirmation </td>
    </tr>;
    }
    Next completed
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `Dim`, curly braces, parentheses and semi-colon from your `For Each` statement. They belong to C# not VB.

```
@For Each row in db.Query(selectQueryString) 
    @<tr>
        <td> @row.email </td>
        <td> @row.password </td>
        <td> @row.requireEmailConfirmation </td>
    </tr>
Next
```

Also, you don't need the parentheses around your `selectQueryString` variable:

```
Dim selectQueryString = "SELECT * From UserProfile BY email"
```

If you want to use VB as your language, you should spend some time learning its syntax and how it works with Razor. Here's a good starting point: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic